# How to discard initial / default select option after first search with Ransack

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ransack

If I specify a default :selected value for months/years below, then it always reverts to these after search. Is there a way to have the selects set to the selection for the search performed rather than the default after the page loads after the search?

I imagine this would require setting the default in the controller once and ignoring them if it is determined that the search is not the first or has other values selected.

```
<%= search_form_for @search, :html => {} do |f| %>
  <div class="control-group">
    <div class="controls form-inline">
      <%= f.select :rollout_month_eq, months, {:selected => months[Date.today.month - 1]} %>
      <%= f.select :rollout_year_eq, years, {:selected => years[1]} %>
      <%= f.submit "Apply" %>
    </div>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be as simple as determining if the parameter is `nil`.

```
<%= search_form_for @search, :html => {} do |f| %>
  <div class="control-group">
    <div class="controls form-inline">
      <%= f.select :rollout_month_eq, months, {:selected => params[:q].try(:[], :rollout_month_eq) || months[Date.today.month - 1]} %>
      <%= f.select :rollout_year_eq, years, {:selected => params[:q].try(:[], :rollout_year_eq) || years[1]} %>
      <%= f.submit "Apply" %>
    </div>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Edited to reflect your parameter structure.

Comment: I implemented something a little more complex where I check if params[:q]["rollout_month_eq"] is nil in the controller, then set a selected month variable accordingly. Your solution doesn't actually seem to work, will fiddle a bit more...

Comment: Thanks, your solution is simpler, but needs a tweak: the param is accessed through :q, so we need to check that :q exists first. This works: 
:selected => params[:q] ? params[:q][:rollout_month_eq] : months[Date.today.month - 1]

Comment: That'll do it, or for an alternative way see my updated answer, taking in to consideration your parameter structure.